# How does % operator in AND evaluate

Tags: sql, sql-server

Found this in the AND condition of LEFT OUTER JOIN between AA & DD

```
 AND DD.EMPL_ID LIKE '%' + AA.[Emp_Id]
```

Can anyone explain what this is evaluating and how?

Comment: The operator is `LIKE`. `'%'` is just a string.

Comment: If DD.EMPL_ID is like a string concatenated with AA.Emp_Id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator does a string comparison but treats `%` and `_` as wildcards matching any string and any single character, respectively. This is analoguous to `*` and `?` in the shell.

```
DD.EMPL_ID LIKE '%' + AA.[Emp_Id]
```

looks like your DBM uses `+` for string concatenation (standard SQL would be `||`). So if `AA.[Emp_id]` is `'hello'`, then that condition becomes

```
DD.EMPL_ID LIKE '%' + 'hello'
```

which is

```
DD.EMPL_ID LIKE '%hello'
```

which checks whether `DD.EMPL_ID` is an arbitrary string followed by `hello`, i.e. whether `DD.EMPL_ID` ends with `hello`.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server and this DD.EMPL_ID LIKE '%hello' makes a lot more sense than DD.EMPL_ID LIKE '%' + AA.[Emp_Id] - Thank you for the answer, I understand now.